Understand the flow of ACPI Generic Event Device (GED), Hardware Error Device (HED) and OS handler
In below ASL code, a GED and a HED are defined.
My understanding of the flow when an hardware error happens is as below:
1. The firmware part

The OSPM subsystem of the OS realizes that interrupts 51 and 243 are associated with GED1 because of the GED1._CRS.
So when the OS sees interrupts 51 and 243, the OSPM will claim the interrupts and invoke the _EVT() method of the GED1 device.
And the _GED1._EVT() will notify HED0 with 0x80 as the notification value.

    Device (GED1) {
        Name (_HID, "ACPI0013")
        Name (_UID, Zero)
        Method (_STA) {
          Return (0xF)
        }
        Name (_CRS, ResourceTemplate () {
          Interrupt (ResourceConsumer, Level, ActiveHigh, Exclusive) { 51 } // Socket 0 GHESv2
          Interrupt (ResourceConsumer, Level, ActiveHigh, Exclusive) { 243 } // Socket 1 GHESv2
        })
        Method (_EVT, 1, Serialized) {
          Switch (ToInteger (Arg0)) {
            Case (51) { // Socket 0 GHESv2
              Notify (HED0, 0x80)
            }
            Case (243) { // Socket 1 GHESv2
              Notify (HED0, 0x80)
            }
          }
        }
    }

    Device (HED0)
    {
        Name (_HID, EISAID ("PNP0C33"))
        Name (_UID, Zero)
    }

2. The Linux part

Linux identifies the HED0 as the Hardware Error Device because of the PNP0C33 value.
And Linux uses the drivers/acpi/hed.c to handle the HED0.
I believe the above Notify (HED0, 0x80) will ultimately hit below code from the drivers/acpi/hed.c.

static void acpi_hed_notify(struct acpi_device *device, u32 event)
{
    blocking_notifier_call_chain(&acpi_hed_notify_list, 0, NULL);
}

3. My questions

Linux matches the drivers/acpi/hed.c to the HED0 device because of the PNP0C33 value for _HID. Is this correct?

I think the 0x80 in Notify (HED0, 0x80) corresponds to the u32 event argument of acpi_hed_notify(). But this argument is not used at all. Then why do we need the specific value 0x80 at all?

How does the Notify(HED0, 0x80) pass information to the acpi_hed_notify() in drivers/acpi/hed.c if such info passing exists?


Thanks.

in the following is what I understand!
I think it is correct to assume that the PNP0C33 value for _HID is used to match the hed.c Linux driver.
Looking at Huang Ying comments on PNP0C33 support:

After receiving notification from ACPI core, it is forwarded to all the
listeners via a notifier chain. The listener such as APEI GHES should
check corresponding error source for new events when notified.

Looking in linux/drivers/acpi/apei/ghes.c, we see that a listener to a queue located in hed.c is set for SCI events:
case ACPI_HEST_NOTIFY_SCI:
case ACPI_HEST_NOTIFY_GSIV:
case ACPI_HEST_NOTIFY_GPIO:
    mutex_lock(&ghes_list_mutex);
    if (list_empty(&ghes_hed))
        register_acpi_hed_notifier(&ghes_notifier_hed);

And the function int register_acpi_hed_notifier(struct notifier_block *nb) is really located into the hed.c source file.
So when an event arrives to hed.c, through the call blocking_notifier_call_chain the static int ghes_proc(struct ghes *ghes) is called, which handles all the shebang.
So it seems that the event parameter is not used because all the handling is done in the ghes module.
